# How to translate Japanese Kanji to Katakana

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

The requirement is to:

> As the user type his/her Japanese Kanji first and last names,
>   automatically fill in the corresponding Japanese Katakana first and
>   last names.

I have been searching for a while now, but I couldn't yet find anything. There seems to be several [jQuery plugins that convert Hiragama to Katakana or Romaji or vice-versa](http://wanakana.com/) but that is not what we need here.

There is one that claims to [translate from Kanji to Kana](https://github.com/ysawa/jquery-auto-kana-input) but I don't think the code matches his description (it only executes the code if the input is `Kana` but that is supposed to be the output!).

Anyway, I need to translate a person's first/last names from `Kanji to Kana`.

How do I do this?

As this needs to happen while the user is filling the form, I am prefer a JavaScript solution (or any pointers to it) but if there are any pointers how to do this in .NET, I'll very much appreciated too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there are several JavaScript solutions online to convert from Kanji, Romaji, Hiragana and Katakana. Check these out and see if they work for you:

- [JQuery Auto Kana Input](https://github.com/ysawa/jquery-auto-kana-input)
- [Kuroshiro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kuroshiro)
- [jp-conversion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jp-conversion)
- [WanaKanaJS](http://wanakana.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried AutoKanaInput and WanaKanaJS and that simply does not fulfill the requirement but Kuroshiro is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

This API provides relatively accurate Kanji to Kana conversion. You can choose either hiragana or katakana as a request parameter.

### [ひらがな化API](https://labs.goo.ne.jp/api/jp/hiragana-translation/)